# Как правильно организовать синхронизацию при помощи selection consistent примитивов

Tags: java, многопоточность

Помогите разобраться что такое *selection consistent* примитивы, и как их правильно применять.

Я так понял что это когда объект монитора - примитив `boolean` потому что он всегда записывается за одну операцию. Но так и не понял что это дает и как конкретно это применить.

Объясните пожалуйста, на каком-нибудь элементарном примере, какую проблему это решает, и как именно этот принцип применять.

Comment: можете дать полную фразу про selection consistent?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman не понял о какой фразе вы говорите?

Comment: фраза в которой было словосочетание selection consistent

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman не помню, а почему вы спрашиваете? В контексте обсуждения jmm. Вопрос в том что если это устойчивое понятие, то наверное и области применения ограничены. Вот про эти области и вопрос.